# Data Driven Maps using MapBox GL (choropleth with base map and fast)

Tags: mapbox, choropleth, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

tl;dr version:  How do we build a fast choropleth map with MapBox GL?

@RyanBaumann posted an example:
See https://ryanbaumann.squarespace.com/blog/2016/1/23/mapbox-gl-create-data-driven-styles

But this example shows loading GeoJSON files directly in javascript.  One question about how to handle large GeoJSON files. Let's say you have a 18M GeoJSON file. And you want to view a map and Data-Driven Styles and do it all efficiently.

For example, I have loaded a large GeoJSON file:

https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/recentsaleslocal.geojson

in this mapbox style:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/fedex1/cijrx09ej007o90lx1g1m5b0j.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmVkZXgxIiwiYSI6ImNpam5jZXZvczAwZnd0b201ajhybXE0OW8ifQ.IumX7VWjU71UjEsKTN4bdw#11/40.7060/-73.9754

and it loads instantly and does not transfer the entire 18M over the network at load time.

But when I use the approach Ryan is showing, it appears that I have to load the entire 18M file over the network at load time. That is much slower especially on a slow network.

I'd like to know is there a way to have data-driven styles AND a base map from mapbox all on the same map?

Here are a few examples:

https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/map.html (loads instantly, has base map, all resides on mapbox studio server. NO data-driven style

https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/testmapboxlayerchoropleth.html (loads very slowly, has base map, base map on mapbox, geojson on another server. Uses data-driven style
https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/testmapboxlayerchoropleth.html (loads instantly, NO base map, seems to be all mapbox-gl generated, Uses data-driven style.

My question is how to get the speed of mapbox AND the data-driven styles AND a base map with streets, etc.

Thanks.

pictures of maps above.

[image: fast nyc map but not data-driven]

fast nyc map but not data-driven

---

[image: fast nyc choropleth but no base map]

fast nyc choropleth but no base map

---

[image: slow choropleth loads 18M over network]

slow choropleth loads 18M over network

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't cover all paint & layout properties (and full fledged data driven styles are actively being worked on here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/1932) but ...

If you upload your GeoJSON document to your Mapbox account it will be converted to vector tiles. You can then add this as a layer on it's own after the `style.load` event:

```
map.on('style.load', function() {
  map.addSource('SOURCENAME', {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "mapbox://mapbox.660ui7x6"
  });
});
```

At this stage you have an unstyled layer you can add paint properties to in a data-driven fashion:

```
var layers = [
  ['#723122', 25000000],
  ['#B86B25', 5000000],
  ['#F2F12D', 0]
];

layers.forEach(function(layer, i) {
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "layer-" + i,
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "SOURCENAME",
    "source-layer": "original",
    "paint": {
      "fill-color": layer[0]
    },
    filter: i == 0 ?
      ['>=', 'population', layer[0]] :
      ['all',
        ['>=', "population", layer[0]],
        ['<', "population", layers[i - 1][0]]
    ]
  });
});
```

The `source-layer` you want to target can be found from the uploaded data page on mapbox.com/data or from it's tilejson doc:

`https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.660ui7x6.json?access_token=<YOURACCESSTOKEN>`

Here's an example that demonstrates this very thing https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/

Comment: Thanks so much @tristen.  This is significantly faster!  The biggest item loaded now is the mapbox-gl.js file at 96K vs. before the geojson file at 18M.  That's a 99% improvement.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: see https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/mapcolor1.html for the faster version.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could encode your GeoJSON files on the serverside and decode them again on the clientside using TopoJSON. That's should cutdown on your bandwidth and thus give a nice speedboost.

> TopoJSON is an extension of GeoJSON that encodes topology. Rather than representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are stitched together from shared line segments called arcs. TopoJSON eliminates redundancy, offering much more compact representations of geometry than with GeoJSON; typical TopoJSON files are 80% smaller than their GeoJSON equivalents. In addition, TopoJSON facilitates applications that use topology, such as topology-preserving shape simplification, automatic map coloring, and cartograms.

- https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

Comment: Thanks @iH8  can you explain more.  I see the advantages of vector tiles to be enormous.  If we reduce 18M by 80% that's still 3.6M.  It appears that vector tiles/mapbox gl only loads what is shown on the screen.  Amazing.